# Пунктуация при однородных членах

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Нужна ли запятая перед словом «только» в следующем предложении?

*Хорошо бы научиться писать дневники(,) только вот такими новеллами, или в крайнем случае хоть бы сюжетами, или даже намеками на сюжет.*

Comment: Первый раз вижу такое домашнее задание. Задали переделать авторскую цитату? Предложить другие знаки препинания? Что всё-таки задали?  Цитата включена в сочинение? А зачем ее тогда редактировать?  Или это упражнение из учебника, но тогда это составители коверкают автора.

Comment: Совершенно верно — коверкают (именно это я и имела в виду в комментарии к Вашему ответу).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще предложение выглядит так (Пришвин М. М. [«Дорога к другу»](https://www.libfox.ru/367223-mihail-prishvin-doroga-k-drugu-dnevniki.html)):

> Хорошо бы научиться писать дневники… новеллами, или в крайнем случае хоть бы сюжетами, или даже намеками на сюжет.

Изменённое предложение остаётся простым; перед словом "[только](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%9E&all=x)", относящимся к первому однородному члену, запятая не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно или вообще ничего не менять у Пришвина (кроме многоточия), или  редактировать предложение так:

(1) *Хорошо бы научиться писать дневники **вот такими новеллами**, или в крайнем случае хоть бы сюжетами, или даже намеками на сюжет.*

(2) *Хорошо бы научиться **писать** дневники, **только писать вот такими новеллами**, или в крайнем случае хоть бы сюжетами, или даже намеками на сюжет.*

Здесь второе сообщение раскрывает содержание  первого (не просто писать, а писать новеллами), **поэтому ставится запятая**. Одной частицы ***только*** для обозначения паузы и постановки запятой недостаточно.

Можно также использовать присоединительный союз ***причем***, тогда пауза тоже будет обозначена:

(3) Хорошо бы научиться **писать** дневники, **причем писать вот такими новеллами**, или в крайнем случае хоть бы сюжетами, или даже намеками на сюжет.

Comment: Не понимаю, **почему** надо коверкать чужое предложение? Не понимаю и ссылок — якобы на автора. (См.: https://mykonspekts.ru/1-160000.html)  И предложение неправильное, и пунктуация при оформлении цитат неправильная. Надо бы написать "по Пришвину", если предложение искажается в угоду "изучения языка". P. S. Поправила и оценила Ваш ответ. А вопрос считаю некорректным (правда, это не вина автора вопроса).

Comment: Римма, я ничего не поняла, наверное, уже просто поздно. У меня вроде бы нет цитат и ссылок. Может, автор и пишет по Пришвину, но он нам таких сведений не сообщал. Так что я могу сделать вид, что ничего про классика не знаю, просто подбираю для этого содержания подходящую форму.  Я думаю, Пришвин вряд ли  бы обиделся и не стал бы настаивать на авторском праве. Настоящие таланты великодушны и щедры. Спасибо за голос.